# WinJS.xhr not passing data in httpRequest to Web Api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, winjs

I'm trying to do a call to a Web Api service using WinJS.xhr

When I do the request everything is passed through correctly except that the data (parameters) is not included in the request.

The web api

```
    [Route("api/Products/GetProductsByCategory")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductsByCategory([FromBody]int categoryId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Some logic to return data
            return Json(_result.AsEnumerable<Models.ProductModel>());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log error to log file
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "There was a error loading the products.  View the log file for more details");
        }
    }
```

The JavaScript I use to do the actual request

```
var url = "http://localhost/rauto.webapi/api/Products/GetProductsByCategory"
var parameters = 6
var options = {
                 url: url,
                 responseType: "json",
                 headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
                 data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
                }

 return WinJS.xhr(options).then(Success, Fail)
```

When I trace the request in Fiddler I get the following raw data

Request:

```
GET http://localhost/rauto.webapi/api/Products/GetProductsByCategory HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Language: en-ZA,en;q=0.7,af;q=0.3
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MSAppHost/2.0;     rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 07:18:03 GMT

[]
```

Why isn't the data attached in the body of the httpRequest?

Comment: 1st; Most common a "GET" request uses the URL for data/parameters, not the body. 2nd; You're data seems incomplete. try changing the "parameters" from "= 6" into " = { categoryId: 6 }"

Comment: I have tried the parameters as { categoryId: 6 } it still has the same result. If I pass the parameter in the URL it works but I need to pass the te parameter in the body.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would let MVC handle it and use the routing in this case. I believe it would be something like:

```
[Route("api/Products/GetProductsByCategory/{categoryId:int}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetProductsByCategory(int categoryId)
{
```

Than just add the parameter to the URL in JavaScript:

```
var url = "http://localhost/rauto.webapi/api/Products/GetProductsByCategory"
var parameters = 6
var options = {
                 url: url+'/'+parameters,
                 responseType: "json",
                 headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
                }

 return WinJS.xhr(options).then(Success, Fail)
```